# Allowing SQL Server concurrency mode with EntityFramework SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency

I'm working with EF 6.0 and SQL Server 2012 Express.
I save 10,000 records to database using DbContext.DbSet.AddRange(IEnumerable) and SaveChanges().

I noticed that when SaveChanges() is called, SQL Server held the connection. Other operations to SQL Server have to wait until 10,00 records are saved.

In this scenario, I don't want SQL server to lock the connection. I want to query data from another table, or read from the same table that is being updated.

**What can I do to enable parallel for SQL Server? Or is it possible to do that?**

Answer (score 1):

To prevent `SaveChanges()` from blocking current thread you can use `SaveChangesAsync()`. This operation will block that instance of `DbContext` but not current thread or database itself. If you are using `new DbContext()` per request, that should be enough. Otherwise you should use new context to do your long insert:

```
  using(var Ctx = new MyDbContext()) {
     ///Add or update objects here
     Ctx.MyDbSet.AddRange(LargeList);
     Ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
  }
```

Remember that selecting from the table you are inserting into might yield unexpected results, depending whether select happened before or after asyc insert finished.